# how does the out keyword determine scope for a variable that was not declared before being passed?

Tags: c#, out

When I call a function that takes an out argument and I don't declare the variable used as the argument before calling it, what is the scope of the new variable?

I've noticed I can do this:

```
if (functionTakesOut(out int newInteger)) {
  Console.WriteLine(newInteger);
}
Console.WriteLine(newInteger);
```

and both Console.WriteLine() calls will work.

Comment: It's C# 7 feature, You just declare newInteger variable in place where you use it, instead of declaring it e.g one line above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example your using the scope would be `local`...because your declaring it as you 
pass it.

Essentially its the same as:

```cs
int newInteger;
if (functionTakesOut(out newInteger)) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(newInteger);
}
Console.WriteLine(newInteger);
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of a followup question. What if I do:    

`if (newInteger > 0 || functionTakesOut(out newInteger)) {}`    

Will the `newInteger > 0` comparison be looking at the value after functionTakesOut() is called? Or will newInteger be undefined there?

Comment: So..functionTakeOut has to return a bool for that line to compile...say it does. If the expression on the left of the || was true...it would never evaluate the right side.

Comment: On the other hand had you just used the regular "or" | operator (and not the short circuit || operator)..then it would evaluate both sides.

Comment: Scope is a static compile time concept so it cannot be influenced by the runtime value of the first condition.

Comment: @KlausGütter...@the8thbit follow up question was about the value and not the scope.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani My question is, what would newInteger be equal to at the point at which `newInteger > 0` is being evaluated? functionTakesOut() has not run yet, but newInteger is not assigned a value until functionTakesOut() is run.

Comment: It would be false. An int has a default value of zero.

Comment: If newInteger was never declared...and you use:   if (newInteger >0 || functionTakesOut(out int newInteger) ...this wont compile.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Thanks for the clarification! This makes sense to me now. :)